I am trying to execute the command 'gradle tasks --all' from command prompt and build is getting failed
C:\Users\firstJavaProject>gradle build

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* Where:
Settings file 'C:\Users\firstJavaProject\settings.gradle' line: 20


* What went wrong:
Plugin [id: 'org.gradle.toolchains.foojay-resolver-convention', version: '0.4.0'] was not found in any of the following sources:

- Gradle Core Plugins (plugin is not in 'org.gradle' namespace)
- Plugin Repositories (could not resolve plugin artifact 'org.gradle.toolchains.foojay-resolver-convention:org.gradle.toolchains.foojay-resolver-convention.gradle.plugin:0.4.0')
  Searched in the following repositories:
    Gradle Central Plugin Repository

    Google
    MavenRepo

* Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 813ms

I have tried using plugin management
Seems it doesn't work in my case, here are my configurations:

Java version: "java 17.0.12 2024-07-16 LTS"
Gradle version: Gradle 8.1.1

settings.gradle file:
plugins {
    // Apply the foojay-resolver plugin to allow automatic download of JDKs
    id 'org.gradle.toolchains.foojay-resolver-convention' version '0.4.0'
}


One can't just add random plugins without also adding the source repository:
https://plugins.gradle.org/plugin/org.gradle.toolchains.foojay-resolver-convention
...which in this case is gradlePluginPortal():
pluginManagement {
    repositories {
        gradlePluginPortal() // this one is missing.
        mavenCentral()
        google()
    }
}

As one can see, you're also using a quite outdated, if not obsolete, version.
And adding plugins in settings.gradle is also a questionable approach ...

I tried using the latest version, i.e., 0.8.0, but somehow this also failed.
I understand adding plugins in settings.gradle file is also a bad approach.

You should instead define that Gradle plugin repository there. You could even download and provide the JAR manually. It makes no difference, while it can find and load it. And when it still behaves the same, you may have wrongfully added it as Java dependency repository, not as Gradle plugin repository. That's not the same.

https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/plugins.html#sec:plugin_management
